# React component can't find redux store props and actions after migration to Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I have app:

```
export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <Router>
                        <Header/>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path="/" component={MainPage}/>
                            <AdminLayout>
                                <Route path="/admin" exact component={AdminMainPage}/>
                                <Route path="/admin/add-user" exact component={AddUserPage}/>
                            </AdminLayout>
                            <Route path="/sign-up" component={SignUpPage}/>
                            <Route path="*" component={NotFound}/>
                        </Switch>
                    </Router>
                </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

In this app I made AdminLayout as class:

```
type AdminLayoutState = {
    contentType: string
};

interface AdminLayoutProps {
}


class AdminLayout extends React.Component<AdminLayoutProps, AdminLayoutState> {
    setActiveMenuItem = (contentType: string) => {

    };

    render() {
        const {
            children,
            adminContentType
        } = this.props

        return (
            <div className="admin-layout">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Row>
                        <Grid.Column width={3}>
                            <MenuLeft
                                contentType={""}
                                onClick={() => this.setActiveMenuItem("")}
                            />
                        </Grid.Column>
                        <Grid.Column width={12}>
                            <div className="admin-layout-content">
                                {children}
                            </div>
                        </Grid.Column>
                    </Grid.Row>
                </Grid>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) =>{
    return {
        adminContentType: state.serviceFlags.adminContentType
    };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    return bindActionCreators(
        {
            setAdminContentType: setAdminContentType
        },
        dispatch
    );
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AdminLayout as any);
```

So, when I'm trying to get adminContentType from props I get error :

```
TS2339: Property 'adminContentType' does not exist on type 'Readonly  & Readonly{ children?: ReactNode; }>'
```

When I want to call action setAdminContentType on onCLick:

```
<MenuLeft
                                contentType={""}
                                onClick={() => this.props.setAdminContentType("")}
                            />
```

I get same error -such property does not exist. How I understand, I did something wrong with using `connect()`(didnt connected component to redux properly), but I don't understand what.

Yes, I understand, that I can do this using hooks, but here I need this component to be a class, not functional component(but hooks only allowed there). Could somebody explain how to connect typescript class-components properly?

Comment: The issue is your component doesn't recognize the props injected by your connect from redux. You should be doing something like this - https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/usage-with-typescript#typing-the-connect-higher-order-component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generics on your `React.Component` need to reflect all of the props that the component receives, including those added by Redux.  When you `export default connect`, the Typescript types for `connect` will drop the added props from the requirements of the connected component.

The `bindActionCreators` in your `mapDispatchToProps` is not necessary.  You can just use [object notation](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object) and it will bind for you automatically.

It seems like the `adminContentType` in your props is the same value as the `contentType` in your state.  In that case, you do not need to have a component state at all.

The type for the `state` argument of `mapStateToProps` is your app's `RootState`, which [you can infer from the store](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/usage-with-typescript#define-root-state-and-dispatch-types) and export.

```
interface AdminLayoutProps {
    adminContentType: string;
    setAdminContentType: (contentType: string) => void;
}

class AdminLayout extends React.Component<AdminLayoutProps> {
    render() {
        const {
            children,
            adminContentType,
            setAdminContentType
        } = this.props

        return (
            <div className="admin-layout">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.Row>
                        <Grid.Column width={3}>
                            <MenuLeft
                                contentType={""}
                                onClick={() => setAdminContentType("")}
                            />
                        </Grid.Column>
                        <Grid.Column width={12}>
                            <div className="admin-layout-content">
                                {children}
                            </div>
                        </Grid.Column>
                    </Grid.Row>
                </Grid>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => {
    return {
        adminContentType: state.serviceFlags.adminContentType
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {setAdminContentType})(AdminLayout);
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/WoqypN)